# I am curious about one equation.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Recently I came across this equation: 
$$f(x)\in L^2(S^2)$$
I am curious about what $L^2(S^2)$ means? Could anyone explain the differences between $f(x)\in L^2(S^2)$ and $f(x)\in R$, or point out some materials about $L^2(S^2)$. Thanks very much.

Comment: $S^2$ is the sphere. $L^2(X)$ is the space of functions $f$ such that $\int_X f^2$ exists.

Comment: as already stated, $L^2$ represents the **square norm** of a normed function (Banach) space whose domain in this case is the (topological space of the) sphere in 2 dimensions ($S^2$), so this represents functions on the 2-dimensional sphere which are square integrable (i.e their square $L^2$ norm) exists and is finite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that $L^2(S^2)$ corresponds to the $L^2$ space on the spherical manifold $S^2$.

Try looking up "intrinsic $L^p$ space", it might help.